# Sum the value of aggregate function in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a column that gets its value from Commission %(percentage is based on a customer # so it can change) multiplied by Profit column by using the following expression:

=Fields!Profit.Value * ReportItems!Commission%.Value

I need to get subtotal for the Commission Total column. When I try to total the commission I get the error:

"The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox91.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers."

I then tried to SUM the value of the textbox by using  =SUM(ReportItems!Textbox65.Value)  but it would only grab the last result and not sum all of them.[image]

The subtotal of the Commission Total column should be 14.64 not 2.13045. I am trying to total the Commission Total column.

Comment: What are you expecting for an answer here? You have provided essentially zero details.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Without a better understanding of the problem, you likely need to sum the Field, not the textbox itself.

Comment: I have tried to clear up spots in the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is that aggregate functions like `Sum` don't like to operate on `ReportItems`. I think that the value in the `Commission%` column comes from an expression that uses elements (or even just one element) of the `Fields` collection, so you just have to use that same expression when calculating the total commission, for example

```
=Sum(Fields!Profit.Value*Fields!Commission%.Value)
```

Comment: The Commission % column gets it value from this expression:


`=IIF(TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "6379" OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "7725" OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "320", .035, 
IIF (TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "8433" OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "5249" OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "1135" 
OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "911"  OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "909" 
OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "1821"  OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "33234" 
OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "9897"  OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "3834",.0175, .08))`

Comment: Very nice, so your total commision should be calculated like this: `=Sum(Fields!Profit.Value*IIF(TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "6379" OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "7725" OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "320", .035, IIF (TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "8433" OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "5249" OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "1135" OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "911" OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "909" OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "1821" OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "33234" OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "9897" OR TRIM(Fields!custno.Value) = "3834",.0175, .08)))`.

Answer (score 0):

I used the report wizard in design view in visual studio and exported to report server and ran, see attached image, commission total is correctly displayed without the use of reportitems.[image]

Comment: Commission Total is clculated using this expression:

=Fields!Profit.Value * ReportItems!Commission%.Value


When I do =SUM(Fields!Profit.Value * ReportItems!Commission%.Value) I get the aggregate function error